# Why am I getting "spring.datasource-user.driverClassName is an unknown property" warning?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, warnings

**Why am I `getting spring.datasource-user.driverClassName is an unknown property` warning?**

I am trying to use jdbc connector for java in my Spring Boot app. Trying to load jdbc properties from `application.properties` file but, above warning showing for the 1st line,

```
spring.datasource-user.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource-user.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/USERSERVICE?autoreconnect = true
spring.datasource-user.username = root
spring.datasource-user.password = root
spring.datasource-user.tomcat.test-on-borrow = true
spring.datasource-user.tomcat.test-while-idle = true
spring.datasource-user.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis = 60000
spring.datasource-user.tomcat.min-evictable-idle-time-millis = 30000
spring.datasource-user.tomcat.validation-query = SELECT 1
spring.datasource-user.tomcat.max-active = 15
spring.datasource-user.tomcat.max-idle = 10
spring.datasource-user.tomcat.max-wait = 8000
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: That isn't a regular property so your IDE will give you this warning. Do you really need a specific datasource due to having multiple? If not don't use the `-user` prefix but stick with the defaults.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes I am using multiple. Its needed.

Comment: Ìt's just a warning (I assume in your IDE) just ignore it. Also if this is your custom datasource I wouldn't use the `spring` namespace but rather your own dedicated one.